# Is it possible to exceed limit of local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Is it possible to exceed the limit of 5mb (or 10mb) of the local storage? For example using the space dedicated to subdomains (but using the same URL / domain)?

Comment: Yes, depending on the browser you are using (some browsers implemented localStorage in a way which means using different sub-domains can be manipulated in that way) - see http://feross.org/fill-disk/ - that does exactly that to fill up a drive completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the spec intends to prevent using subdomains to get more space. Here's the spec:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space

Basically it's not possible. Maybe you can use `indexedDB` instead.